# only access with url which I write on htaccess prevent accessing real url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have folder `admin`
And I have changed url from `admin` to `admin-cdn` with below rule

```
RewriteRule ^admin-cdn/?(.*)$ admin/$1 [L]
```

Now I can access admin folder's files with both `www.domain.com/admin/` and `www.domain.com/admin-cdn/` url

I want show 404 error when user what to access with `www.domain.com/admin` path

How can do this in **.htaccess** file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# if /admin/ is entered as URL then send 404
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/admin[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

# internal rewrite from /admin-cdn/ to /admin/
RewriteRule ^admin-cdn(/.*)?$ admin$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Can you explain like how can I change url to "admincdn" only

Comment: For that use `RewriteRule ^admincdn(/.*)?$ admin$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: What is the meaning of this ```RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]```

Comment: @Narsingitkampalli `RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]` means Any URIs that passes through this rule will get a 404 error.

Comment: when I hit wrong folder name with url like ```/admin-cdn/images/``` if ```images``` folder exist than it works fine if ```images``` folder not exist than it redirecting to ```/admin``` path

Comment: There is no redirect in these rules. It only rewrites to `/admin/` folder. If a path i.e. `/admin/foobar` doesn't exist then it should show `404` page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^admin/ - [L,R=404]
RewriteRule ^admin-cdn/?(.*)$ admin/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Now it prevent access for "admin" url and also prevent for "admin-cdn". How to solve this.

Comment: I tried this before also but It was not working.